# How to post form data as JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to build a registration site for a group project we are working on but can't figure out how to send the form data as json. I've tried googling a lot and changing the code but nothing seems to work. The problem I have is that when i press on the submit button I get an error like this from the API:

> {"":["The input was not valid."]}

I think the reason is that my form does not send the data as JSON and it's they format they require according to their API documentation. My form code looks like this:

```
<form id="register_form" action="https://https://url.com/users/register" method="post">
        <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" placeholder="Name" name="name" title="Up to 20 alphabetical characters" required>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" title="Must be a valid email address" required>
        <input type="password" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-]+{8,20}" placeholder="Password" name="password" title="Must be 8 or more characters long and contain at least one number and one uppercase letter" required>
        <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-]+" placeholder="Homeadress" name="homeadress">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Postnumber" name="postnumber">
        <input type="text" placeholder="City" name="city">
        <br>
        <button value="Submit" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

And the script i've been trying to get to work looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('register_form').on('submit', function(event){

    var obj = $('register_form').serializeJSON();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://url.com/users/register',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType : 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
        }
    });

   return false;
 });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm not very familiar with coding stuff like this.

Edit:

I also tried it with a script like this but still getting the same response:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").on('click', function(){

   var formData = {

        "name": $('input[name=name]').val(),
        "email": $('input[name=email]').val(),
        "password": $('input[name=password]').val(),
        "homeadress": $('input[name=homeadress]').val(),
        "postnumber": $('input[name=postnumber]').val(),
        "city": $('input[name=city]').val()
    };

       $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: 'https://url.com/users/register', 
        type : "POST", 
        dataType : 'json', 
        data : JSON.stringify(formData), 
        success : function(result) {

            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
            console.log(xhr, resp, text);
        }
    })
});
});
```

I tested it with our teachers test api also and the response is this:

> {"message":"Bad Request","reason":"val: nil fails spec: :user-system.spec/login-request predicate: map?\n"}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple problems here.

1. Invalid start tag for script element. This was probably a copy and paste error, but worth mentioning:

   ```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
                                                    missing greater than symbol ^
   ```
2. Selecting `register_form` instead of `#register_form` in two places, the second was unnecessary regardless because you could reference `this` instead. This also resulted in the form submission not being cancelled.
3. You didn't include a `$.serializeJSON` plugin, again I'm assuming this is a copy and paste error.
4. `$.serializeJSON` (whichever you choose) should return a JSON string, but you run `JSON.stringify` on the result, which will be a string inside a string.
5. `https://https://` This isn't a huge issue because it is in the `action` attribute of a form that should never submit, but worth mentioning.

In the example below I've provided a simple replacement for `$.serializeJSON`, and corrected the rest of the issues listed above. `serialize_form` in the code below can be replaced with whatever `$.serializeJSON` plugin you choose to use.

I have commented out the ajax request as what is really of concern here is getting the JSON from the form data, so I just log it to the console instead so that you can see it is a JSON string. I also removed the pattern attributes and required flags from the input for ease of testing.

```js
const serialize_form = form => JSON.stringify(
  Array.from(new FormData(form).entries())
       .reduce((m, [ key, value ]) => Object.assign(m, { [key]: value }), {})
);

$('#register_form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const json = serialize_form(this);
  console.log(json);
  /*$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://url.com/users/register',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: json,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data)
    }
  });*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="register_form" action="https://url.com/users/register" method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" title="Up to 20 alphabetical characters">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" title="Must be a valid email address">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" title="Must be 8 or more characters long and contain at least one number and one uppercase letter">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Homeadress" name="homeadress">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Postnumber" name="postnumber">
  <input type="text" placeholder="City" name="city">
  <br>
  <button value="Submit" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed the typos and tried it with the ajax commented out and i got the data as JSON in the console. Do you see any big mistakes in my ajax code since when i uncomment it I get the same error from the site? Or does this imply that the problem is something else since I can clearly see that it converts the form data to JSON with your example?

Comment: @paranoid The AJAX looks fine, I'll test it on my local system in a bit to make sure. It has to be something else. Check the spelling of the field names. `homeadress` might need to be spelled `homeaddress` for example. Remember field names are case sensitive as well.

Comment: Oh, I missed the part that there's a spec for the request format. Could you put it up on gist and send me a link?

Comment: I tried it with restlet and there the api accepts the data in this form so I don't think it's the spelling, i can pm you the url for the api if you have time to test it on your own pc, it's for a school project and I don't want to share the other groups api link to everyone.

Comment: Oh, you apparently can't send private messages on stackoverflow. Can I add you on discord or something else? @Tiny Giant

Comment: @paranoid I set your script up locally and I got an error _"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."_ So I injected the script into the root page of the API page you linked me so that it would be on the same origin, and it all worked as expected. I'm guessing that you're running your script on a different origin than the API, which is causing the error. (Also, the script I downloaded from the email was missing a `$` before `.ajax` but I'm guessing that was a copy-paste error.)

Comment: By "worked as expected" I mean the server responded with an object containing a property named `x-auth-token` with a value of `"BBgqtB3pyKLxlAQAKBe9j4NsoQfbdaHeQMxUW4VPhKS5SLwfBD207GSqEcHcIgzmMBc2gMW1zHeScbDSkPf56Q=="`

Comment: Allright thanks a lot! Is there anything I could do to get it to work without the same origin or is it something that needs to be done on the back-end side? @TIny Giant

Comment: @paranoid there's things you can do with userscripts or browser extensions because you can bypass the browsers CORS restrictions, but not on a regular web page. You would have to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` for the response from the server side to allow access from a different origin. It isn't very difficult if you have access to the back end.

Comment: I downloaded some browser extension and it seems to work with that, I need to talk with the group who handles the back end so I don't need the extension. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: i tried above code and works fine but can only set last value of `multiple select`, how to include the selected list as json value?