# How i can submit file in FormData with json format to server php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit form by using formdata(). I need to get all data into json format, but due to file attachment i'm unable to do this in JSON.

Source Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('submit', '.career', function(e){e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("username", "test");
        formData.append("acct", 23323);
        var data = JSON.stringify(formData);
        $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: ajax.asyncUrl,
              processData: false,
              data: formData
        })
    .done(ajax.callbacks.submitAp);
```

Can any one please help me out about this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53107833/how-to-post-form-data-as-json

Comment: You cannot send formData as JSON. It's either/or, but not both. If you require specific help on how to fix your problem, please add your code to the question.

Comment: RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your conmment, can you please check again my updated post.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot JSON encode the binary data within a FormData object. To send FormData you need to supply it to the `data` property of the settings object in `$.ajax()`, and also set both `contentType` and `processData` to `false`. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '.career-form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("username", "Groucho");
  formData.append("accountnum", 123456);
  // add file data here...
  
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: ajax.asyncUrl,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
  }).done(ajax.callbacks.submitCareerApplicationLite);
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, but actually i need to send json object to back end I doesn't want to change my back end functionality which is generic for all requests. ```` {requestname: 'submitsApplication', data:formData } ````, formData should also include into json format with files.

Comment: You cannot do that. To be able to send formdata you need to send it as the above JS code shows. As such you will have to change your back end logic.

Comment: No problem, glad to help