# JavaScript Fetch() with a HTTP PUT is not sending FormData to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, put

I'm using a PHP rest API to post data from JS client to a PHP 8 server.
I'm using the JS `fetch()` method. When using `POST` the formdata is send to PHP's global $_POST, but since I need to update data I have to use `PUT`. Somehow Google Chrome is not sending the formdata to the server and I don't know why. Somebody knows the reason?

```
JS:

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', 'Hello world');

const options = {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(formData);
    cache: 'no-cache',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrer: 'no-referrer',
    
    // Not working either
    // headers: {
    //     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8;'
    // },
};

fetch('/some/api/v1', options);
```

```
PHP 8 server:

var_dump($_REQUEST); // NULL
```

Comment: You can't JSON.stringify `FormData`. Just send that as body. Browser knows how to serialize it. See Upload File example in [MDN Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file)

Comment: Or for simple case like shown don't bother using FormData and send stringified plain object as JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not on the client but on the server. Both Firefox and Chrome serialize the data and send it with this code:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let fd = new FormData(this);
            fetch('test.php', {method:'PUT', body:fd})
            .then(function(response){
                response.text().then(function(txt){console.log("Response:"+txt);});
            });
        });
```

The problem is with PHP support for `PUT`, which doesn't automatically unpack the data for you. You can get it from the `stdin` stream.

```
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024)) {
    echo $data;
}
```

Response:

```
-----------------------------256278305409917102757952731 
Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name="myText" ffsssssdd 
-----------------------------256278305409917102757952731--
```

If you want to send your form data as a JSON object you can use this:

```
const serialize_form = form => JSON.stringify(
    Array.from(new FormData(form).entries())
        .reduce((m, [ key, value ]) => Object.assign(m, { [key]: value }), {})
        );
           
const json = serialize_form(this);
fetch('test.php', {method:'PUT', body:json, headers:{'content-type':'application/json'}})
    .then(function(response){
         response.text().then(function(txt){console.log("Response:"+txt);});
                });
```

Response:

```
{"myText":"ghfghfghfg"}
```

the `serialize_form` function taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111979/14853083)

See the [PHP reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php)

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer and code example! I didn't knew that PUT is not automatically unpacked by PHP. I was able to solve the issue, once again thanks!